# Join two table to be one record

Tags: mysql, sql, join

i have two table like this [image] and I want to join these two tables into this

```
Student ID SubjectID UTS UAS
1          1         80  80
1          2         88  88
```

Thanks for helping.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Step 1. Don't have two tables

Comment: Your schema is a mess. You need a student table, subject table, and a score table that has the UAS, UTS labels in it. Then a fourth table that joins the other three and has the scores in it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply Use [**Inner Join**](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-inner-join.aspx)

```
SELECT A.*, B.UAS
FROM tbl1 AS A JOIN tbl2 AS B ON A.StudentID = B.StudentID AND A.SubjectID = B.SubjectID
```

Comment: This is a disaster because when you add another thing in the UAS/UTS category you will need another table and all your queries will break.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.UAS
    FROM uts AS t1 
    LEFT JOIN uas AS t2
        ON t1.StudentID = t2.StudentID AND t1.SubjectID = t2.SubjectID
```

You just have to join the two tables on the two common columns.

Answer (score 0):

A JOIN clause is used to combine rows from two or more tables, based on a related column between them.

```
   select t1.*,t2.UAS from table1 t1 
     inner join table2 t2 
     ON t1.StudentID = t2.StudentID AND
     t1.SubjectID = t2.SubjectID
```

for details about join you can read some tutorials 
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Comment: This definitely won't work, you're joining on a single column while there are 2 in common, and you're not retrieving UAS from the second table.

Comment: @AntoineB  If you have no reason then fine, you are welcome to put down vote thanks

Comment: @Pyon two answer were given before that one  you accept interesting :)